# A menu implemented as a switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

I want to create a menu and I need to create in this menu some cars (Car, Model, Color, Price). I also need to modify or delete from this menu the cars.

Here's my code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct automobil
{
    unsigned nr;
    char Marca, Model, Culoare, Tara;
    float Pret;
} *VA[40];


int main()
{
    unsigned n, men;
    do
    {
        printf("Crearea vectorului ---- 1\n");
        printf("Afisarea datelor   ---- 2\n");
        printf("Adaugarea          ---- 3\n");
        printf("Modificarea        ---- 4\n");
        printf("Eliminarea         ---- 5\n");
        printf("Iesire             ---- 6\n");
        scanf("%u", &men);
        switch(men)
        {
            case 1: n = Intr(0); break;
            case 2: Afis(n); break;
            case 3: n = Intr(n); break;
            case 4: Modif(n); break;
            case 5: n = Elim(n); break;
        }
    }
    while (men != 0);

    unsigned Intr(unsigned i)
    {
        char rasp;
        do
        {
            VA[i].nr = i;
            printf("Introduceti Marca, Modelul, Culoarea, Tara si Pretul automobilului %u\n",i);
            scanf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %f", &VA[i].Marca, &VA[i].Model, &VA[i].Culoare, &VA[i].Tara, &VA[i].Pret);
            gets(VA[i].Marca);
            gets(VA[i].Model);
            printf("Mai introduceti date? [d / n]\n");
            scanf("%c", &rasp);
            i++;
        }
        while (rasp == 'd');
            return i;
    }

    void Afis(unsigned m)
    {
        unsigned i;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                printf("%u\n", VA[i].nr);
                puts(VA[i].Marca);
                puts(VA[i].Model);
                puts(VA[i].Culoare);
                puts(VA[i].Tara);
                printf("%f\n", VA[i].Pret);
            }
        getch();
    }

    void Modif(unsigned m)
    {
        unsigned i;
        Afis(m);
        printf("Introduceti numarul automobilului, datele carora le modificati.\n");
        scanf("%u", &nr);
            if (i >= m)
            {
                printf("Nr. inexistent!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Introduceti Marca, Modelul, Culoarea si Tara.\n");
                gets(VA[i].Marca);
                gets(VA[i].Model);
                gets(VA[i].Culoare);
                gets(VA[i].Tara);
                scanf("%f", &VA[i].Pret);
            }
    }

    unsigned Elim(unsigned m)
    {
        unsigned i;
        char rasp;
            do
            {
                Afis(m);
                printf("Nr de Automobile.\n");
                scanf("%u", &i);
                    if (i >= m)
                    {
                        printf("Numar inexistent.\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int j = i; j < m-1; j++)
                        {
                            VA[j] = VA[j+1];
                            m--;
                        }
                    }
                printf("Mai eliminati automobile? [d / n]\n");
                scanf("%c", &rasp);
            }
                while (rasp == 'd');
                return m;
    }
}
```

The error messages I get are as follows:

```
In function 'int main()':
25:23: error: 'Intr' was not declared in this scope "case 1: n = Intr(0); break;"
26:19: error: 'Afis' was not declared in this scope "case 2: Afis(n); break;"
28:20: error: 'Modif' was not declared in this scope "case 4: Modif(n); break;"
29:23: error: 'Elim' was not declared in this scope "case 5: n = Elim(n); break;"
35:3: error: a function-definition is not allowed here "before '{' token {"
115:2: error: expected '}' at end of input }
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: @alexander have you declared the prototype of the functions ?

Comment: The reason some words are not allowed in the topic is a good one. So intentionally putting an extra `p` in it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1. Indent your code properly. You're missing the closing brace `}` for `main()` after the `while ();`

Point 2. You need to have the forward declaration of the functions used in `main()` but defined later. Otherwise, better, define all other functions before `main()` (define before usage).

After you fix these things, the next pain will be produced by `scanf("%c", &rasp);`. This will *eat* the remaining <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press after the last input. Better to use `scanf(" %c", &rasp);` kind of statement.

Next, while usually `unsigned i;` will default to `unsigned int i;`, IMHO it is better to use the later form.

Comment: Point 2a. Just putting the definitions before their first use is easier and less error-prone.

Comment: @Deduplicator You're a mind-reader. Was updating the same. :-)